# PDOエラーについて

Tags: php, pdo

メッセージ投稿機能を作っていた際、下記のようなエラーメッセージが表示されました。この場合、どう対処すれば良いのでしょうか。

array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }

ちなみに、以下がindex.phpのコードです

```
<?php
session_start();
require('dbconnect.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && $_SESSION['time']+ 3600> time()) {
  $_SESSION['time'] = time();

  $members = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM members WHERE id=?');
  $members->execute(array($_SESSION['id']));
  $member = $members->fetch();
} else {
  header('Location: login.php');
  exit();
}
if (!empty($_POST)) {
  if ($_POST['message'] !== '') {
    $message = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO posts SET member_id=?, message=?, created=NOW()');
    $message->execute(array(
      $memeber['id'],
      $_POST['message']
    ));
    var_dump($message->errorInfo()); // ここ
    exit();

    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
  }
}
$posts = $db->query('SELECT m.name, m.picture, p.* FROM members m, posts p WHERE m.id=p.member_id ORDER BY created DESC');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>ひとこと掲示板</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="head">
    <h1>ひとこと掲示板</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div style="text-align: right"><a href="logout.php">ログアウト</a></div>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <dl>
        <dt><?php echo htmlspecialchars($member['name'], ENT_QUOTES) ?>さん、メッセージをどうぞ</dt>
        <dd>
          <textarea name="message" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
          <input type="hidden" name="reply_post_id" value="" />
        </dd>
      </dl>
      <div>
        <p>
          <input type="submit" value="投稿する" />
        </p>
      </div>
    </form>

<?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
    <div class="msg">
    <img src="member_picture/<?php echo htmlspecialchars($post['picture'], ENT_QUOTES) ?>" width="48" height="48" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($post['name'], ENT_QUOTES) ?>" />
    <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($post['message'], ENT_QUOTES) ?><span class="name">（<?php echo htmlspecialchars($post['name'], ENT_QUOTES) ?>）</span>[<a href="index.php?res=">Re</a>]</p>
    <p class="day"><a href="view.php?id="><?php echo htmlspecialchars($post['created'], ENT_QUOTES) ?></a>
<a href="view.php?id=">
返信元のメッセージ</a>
[<a href="delete.php?id="
style="color: #F33;">削除</a>]
    </p>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<ul class="paging">
<li><a href="index.php?page=">前のページへ</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?page=">次のページへ</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

それは「エラーメッセージ」ではありません。

[`PDOStatement::errorInfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/pdostatement.errorinfo.php)は、SQLの実行が成功しても失敗しても、必ず要素数が3の配列を返します。

その第[0]要素は、

> 0   SQLSTATE エラーコード (これは、ANSI SQL 標準で定義された英数 5 文字の ID)

とあります。あなたが取得した`"00000"`は、正常終了を表すコードですので、SQLの実行が成功したことを表しています。

それを`var_dump`すれば、必ず`array(3) { [0]=> ... }`といった出力がされますが、第[0]要素が`"00000"`ならば成功なので、`exit()`で強制終了する必要はありません。正常時の処理を続けてください。

---

ただし、[`PDOStatement::execute`](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/pdostatement.execute.php)の戻り値は、

> #### 返り値
>
> ---
>
> 成功した場合に **`TRUE`** を、失敗した場合に **`FALSE`** を返します。

とありますので、戻り値が **`TRUE`** の場合には`errorInfo()`を参照する必要はありません。

```
if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
    if ($_POST['message'] !== '') {
        $message = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO posts SET member_id=?, message=?, created=NOW()');
        $success = $message->execute(array(
            $memeber['id'],
            $_POST['message']
        ));
        if( $success ) {
            //`execute`が成功したときの処理
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        } else {
            //`execute`が失敗したときの処理
            var_dump($message->errorInfo()); 
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

コードの他の部分はほとんど読んでいないので、「`execute`が成功したとき」にも所望の動作とならないのかもしれませんが、それは`errorInfo()`の今回の出力結果とは関係ありません。